# How can I get information from the user telegram bot?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telepot

For example, the bot sends "Send me your name", "Send me your last name" and saves this data in two variables.my language is python and i used telepot package for make the bot

Comment: Check out this link https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot

Comment: thank you. Do you have a simple example in this modules?I didn't work with this module

Comment: If you scroll down in the link there are examples

Comment: I see the examples.These examples use logging module, because my python version is 3.4, i cant use logging module.

Comment: Thank you, i searched the google and i find another examples that don't use of logging module.I use telegram.ext and i get reply. Please answer and i vote you

Answer (score 0):

In telepot package:

```
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
import time
bot = telepot.Bot('my_token')
def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    send1 = bot.sendMessage(chat_id,'whats your name?')
    if send1:
        text1 = msg['text']
        print(text1)


MessageLoop(bot,handle).run_as_thread()
while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
```

text1 variable is the reply associate to question "whats your name?"